# mediaPlayer single Instance

Tags: android, android-intent, instance, android-mediaplayer

I got a bug on my MediaPlayer.
When i click on an item of my playlist, it create a mp3Player. If i press back the music play in background (all is normal). But if i choose another song from my app, the app create a new mediaplayer:
Then i got 2 music playing !

I tried to use "singleTask", "singleInstance", and it's not working.
I tried "intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);"
None of this work!

Maybe if i could resume the previous Activity, i could destroy it and then create a nex mediaplayer no?
Can someone help please? :D

Comment: Have you tried a `Singleton` instance of the MediaPlayer class you are using?

Comment: singleton is something i think about but i don't really get the design!

maybe you got a good tutorial for me? :D cause i can't find one who match with me

Comment: To put it simple, a Singleton is a class whose constructor will always yeld the same object. [Even wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) has an implementation example. The thing here, is understanding the process... basically, instead of having the constructor build the object, have it built once, and then save it on ram, untill used/needed;

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make your activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" in manifest.
and then in your activity overide below method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // do what you want here
}
```

in above method, you can reset value of media player

Comment: this method will be called whenever you call the activity via startActivity(intent) method

Comment: so i just put that on my code and it gonna make all nice? or i have to add other methods in it

Comment: oh i think i got it: below super.onNewInstance() i just put: mediaPlayer.reset(); Right?

Comment: can we chat? should be better for me! my email is pierrecharlesmangin@hotmail.fr

Answer (score 0):

You play music in backround it means you use Service ?
Problem is  you need reconnect with Service (Service play music).

[How to reconnect service android](https://www.google.com/search?q=reconect%20service%20android&oq=reconect%20service%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57.8991j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20reconnect%20service%20android)

Or try. [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) , EG: [Universal Android Music Player Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer)

Comment: i don't use service. Is that bad?